# find cannot do on having space within string variable for -path or -iregex or etc

Tags: find, variable, string

Cannot have space within string  variable for -path or -iregex find's option.
This input `'/home/demo.*/\.config/File System/.*t$'`
is fed on:

```
read i


m="-iregex $i"
find ~ $m
```

won't work as it will if constant, not variable
so is not `find ~ \'$m\'` nor  `eval find ~ \'$m\'`
How's the correct solution ?

Comment: Why not `find ~ -iregex "$i"`? Please explain this in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put actions into a string variable that contains the data (see [Bash FAQ 50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). And always double-quote your variables when you use them

```
i='/home/demo.*/\.config/File System/.*t$'
find ~ -iregex "$i"
```

If you want to include the `-iregex` only if `$i` is not empty then you can do something like this, which keeps it but replaces the regular expression with `.*` (i.e. anything)

```
find ~ -iregex "${i-.*}"
```

If you are using a shell such as `bash` (but not `sh`) that understands arrays you can use one to include the `-iregex` only if needed

```
IFS= read -r i

findRegex=()
[[ -n "$i" ]] && findRegex=('-iregex' "$i")

find ~ "${findRegex[@]}"
```

To see what's going on here you can modify `find` to `echo find`. Reading `man bash` and searching for `Arrays` and/or `@` may also help.

Notice I've also changed your `read i` to `IFS= read -r i`. This stops the shell trying to parse your input data, which can break expressions containing multiple spaces (characters in `$IFS` to be precise) and other character combinations

Comment: Technically, without IFS=, the problem would be for input that start or end in SPC or TAB (assuming those characters are in `$IFS` as they are by default), and if `$IFS` contains other characters, for input that ends in any of those characters and there's no other `$IFS` character in the input.

Comment: Yes. In this particular instance I'm trying to keep the explanation simple enough to be heeded by the OP